# stop form using javascript? what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

```
   <form onsubmit="return false">
```

That's works. But

```
     <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="off()">
     function off(){return false);
```

Not works

Answer (score 6):

You need the return value.

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return off();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return off();" action="">
```